# Writing minimax algorithms in bash

Tags: bash, unix, minimax

I apologise for the vague question, i am totally lost and have no idea what went wrong at the moment.

I have been trying to learn bash scripting recently and decided to write a tictactoe with minimax and alpha beta pruning. I wrote the script in a very pythonic way since i am still very new to UNIX in general. when i tried running the minimax function, i didn't get any errors but it didn't output anything nor did it exit normally (had to CTRL C).

if the current board is won, the function is able to tell that it is won and return what i need it to. But when it is not won, it is unable to go down to the next level.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a board=( A1 " o" " x" " o" " o" " x" C1 C2 C3 )
shopt -s extglob


#draws the grid
draw(){
grid="| "${board[0]}" | ${board[1]} | ${board[2]} |
----------------
| ${board[3]} | ${board[4]} | ${board[5]} |
----------------
| ${board[6]} | ${board[7]} | ${board[8]} |" 

echo "$grid"
}

#test if board has a winning combination for either player
wintest(){
local testboard=("$@")
for p in " o" " x"
do
#test for vertical win
for i in $(seq 0 2) 
    do
        if [ "$p" == "${testboard[$i]}" -a "$p" == "${testboard[$(($i+3))]}" -a "$p" == "${testboard[$(($i+6))]}" ]; then
        echo 1
        fi
    done
#test for horizontal win
for i in 0 3 6 
    do  
        if [ "$p" == "${testboard[$i]}" -a "$p" == "${testboard[$i+1]}" -a "$p" == "${testboard[$i+2]}" ]; then
        echo 1
        fi
    done
#diagonal win   
if [ "$p" == "${testboard[0]}" -a "$p" == "${testboard[4]}" -a "$p" == "${testboard[8]}" ]; then
echo 1
fi
if [ "$p" == "${testboard[2]}" -a "$p" == "${testboard[4]}" -a "$p" == "${testboard[6]}" ]; then
echo 1
fi
done
}

#minimax function. parameters: player depth alpha beta board
minimax(){
if [ $1 -eq 1 ]; then
local player="1"
local p=" o"

elif [ $1 -eq 2 ]; then 
local player="2"
local p=" x"
fi

local depth=$2
local alpha=$3
local beta=$4

shift 4

#create array amove containing available moves
local boardc=("$@") 
local amove=("${boardc[@]/+(" x"|" o")}")
for i in "${!amove[@]}"; do 
if [[ -z "${amove[$i]}" ]]; then
unset amove[$i]
fi
done

#determine if anybody has won in the current board
#$player=1 is the maximing player. wintest is called on the start of the turn,
#if a winning combination exist, it belongs to the previous player

local winstat=$(wintest "${boardc[@]}")
if [ -n "$winstat" ]; then
    if [ "${player}" == 2 ]; then   
    echo "$depth"

    else  
    echo "-$depth"
    fi

else
    if [ "${player}" == 1 ]; then
    local bestval=-1000
        for i in "${amove[@]}"
        do      
            local boardcm="${boardc[@]}"    
            boardcm=("${boardcm[@]/"$i"/"$p"}")
            local value="$( minimax 2 $(( $depth+1 )) $alpha $beta "${boardcm[@]}" )"
            bestval=$(( "$bestval" > "$value" ? $bestval : "$value" ))
            alpha=$(( "$bestval" > "$alpha" ? "$bestval" : "$alpha" ))
            if [ "$beta" -le "$alpha" ] 
            then 
            break
            fi
        done
        echo "$bestval"

    elif [ "${player}" == 2 ]; then
    local bestval=1000
        for i in "${amove[@]}"
        do      
            local boardcm="${boardc[@]}"    
            boardcm=("${boardcm[@]/"$i"/"$p"}")
            local value="$( minimax 1 $(( $depth+1 )) $alpha $beta "${boardcm[@]}" )"
            bestval=$(( "$bestval" < "$value" ? "$bestval" : "$value" ))
            beta=$(( "$bestval" < "$beta" ? "$bestval" : "$beta" ))
            if [ "$beta" -le "$alpha" ]; then 
            break
            fi
        done
        echo "$bestval"
    fi
fi
}
```

In theory, the minimax function should return a single value that is the highest(or lowest depending on the player) value that can be assured in the current state of the board. The function works until the part where the recursion happens.

I am sorry for not being able to be more detailed in my question, i truly have no idea why the function does not work

Comment: Post your script in https://www.shellcheck.net/ and try fixing all the errors/warnings thrown. In most cases, that should solve any inherent logical problems in your script too

Comment: yea i know, it is more to understand how bash works. I thought it would be a fun project. It is not fun......

Comment: I try to run your code but nothing happened - where/how do you call the functions?

Comment: There is another function for the AI turn which basically just calls the minimax function for all available moves.

you can run the fx minimax on its own, the parameters for the fx are: player, depth, alpha, beta, board. You can add ` minimax 2 5 -1000 1000 "${board[@]}" ` to the bottom of the script to call the function.

Comment: BTW, `==` isn't a valid string comparison operator in POSIX `[`, and `-a` and `-o` operators as AND and OR are marked obsolescent. Use `=` for string comparisons to be compatible with POSIX-baseline shells, and use `[ foo ] && [ bar ]` to combine multiple tests to avoid the nasty corner cases that *caused* that functionality to be marked obsolescent.

Comment: Beyond that, running `PS4=':$LINENO+' bash -x yourscript` to log each command with its associated line number (so you can identify with specificity the first command that doesn't do what you want/expect it to) will do a lot of good towards being able to identify a specific failure; right now, without being narrowed to a specific problem, this is really too broad to be a good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: (Also, to declare a local *array*, use  `local -a`, not just bare `local`).